# Importerror- no module name pyserial and cv2

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, sudo, pyserial, systemctl

I am using jatson nano with ubuntu bionic 18.04.6 LTS.
I have installed pyserial and opencv with these commands

pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
sudo apt-get install python3-serial

if i check these libraries by using pip3 list then it shows
only this 'pyserial (3.5)' but no opencv

code is running fine but when i run my code on boot using systemctl then it is giving me module error.

systemctl script is:

```
[Unit]
Description = code on boot
After = multi-user.target

[Service]
Environment = DISPLAY=:0
Environment = XAUTHORITY= /home/root/.Xauthority
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3 /home/root/code.py
User = root
TimeoutSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

please,help, i am new in this field

basically,jatson nano is reading serial data from Rx Tx, and it is reading quite good but after running on boot, it is giving me this error

Comment: If the installation was successful you'd see the opencv on the list as well, so it looks like it failed. Probably you should use a venv install the libs there and activate it in your `ExecStart` entrypoint, then you'd be sure which python interpreter you are using and what libraries it has access to.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, let me try it, the i will tell you about it